# React Native using Expo : Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1

Tags: react-native

***I am trying to run a sample program in react using expo***

***I used:*** `E:\ReactNative\Samples\rn-starter>npm start`

**I am getting error :**

```
> @ start E:\ReactNative\Samples\rn-starter
> expo start

Starting project at E:\ReactNative\Samples\rn-starter
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\@expo\xdl@56.8.0\src\Project.ts:1834:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Devrath\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-20T08_48_21_094Z-debug.log
```

---

Comment: which version of expo-cli are you running? Also try `expo start -c`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it happened when i updated the Node.Js version to 12.13.1, it seems that it's an error in the interpretation of a regular expression:

**Option N° 1 :**

Inside your project go to

> \node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

Change :

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

To

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

**Option N° 2:**

> Downgrade your Node.js version to 12.9 or older

Hope this will help you.